# Type of C# project to add common entities

Tags: c#, architecture, asp.net-mvc-5

I have very basic question. I am developing a MVC5 project and I want to add  projects for my DTOs, services and service Interfaces in my solution. And then want to reference them in my Web project.
Since I am newbie, I don't know which type of project to choose from.

I tried adding a C# console project and then tried adding its reference to my Web project. But VS2015 is throwing a error that this project reference cannot be added.

Please help me finda solution to this problem.

Note: I am not trying to add any existing project and building the application from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add class library instead of console application.

Answer (score -1):

Got the answer. It's Class Library type.

Comment: BTW prefer .NET Standard library if you're in VS 2017